# How to report the interaction effect in the paper?

Tags: confidence-interval, interaction, multicollinearity, structural-equation-modeling, mplus

I am calculating the moderation (interaction) effect of one variable on the relationship between two variables using Mplus. All of them are continuous variables. Before I calculated the interaction term, I standardized two independent continuous variables to prevent multicollinearity. After providing this preliminary information, I have two questions about reporting the results of moderation analysis in the paper:

1. Should I report the standardized or unstandardized results of the interaction effect in the paper?
2. When reporting the results, is it necessary to include 95% confidence interval (CI) results?

Answer (score 7):

As an aside, you don't need to standardize variables in an interaction to prevent collinearity. Mean centering is enough. And that may be better.

But, to your question: How and what you should report in a paper is up to the place you are submitting it to. Journals have style manuals. Many journals, especially in the social sciences, use the American Psychological Association style manual, which is quite thorough. It is available in all sorts of formats. However, you should check with the particular journal.

My own preference is to report *both* the standardized and unstandardized parameter estimates and to include the 95% CI.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have standardised the variables which account for the interaction term based on the following explanation "If both of the independent variables are continuous, it is helpful for interpretation to either center or standardize the independent variables, X and Z. (Centering involves subtracting the overall sample mean score from the original score; standardizing does the same followed by dividing by the overall sample standard deviation.)" 
Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderation_(statistics)#cite_note-3

Comment: Yes, I didn't say standardizing was wrong, just not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Page 40 of [Kline's text on structural equation models](https://www.guilford.com/books/Principles-and-Practice-of-Structural-Equation-Modeling/Rex-Kline/9781462551910) has a reporting guideline that is quite useful. A relevant section he outlines, which I agree with, mimics what was already noted by Peter:

> - Report unstandardized and standardized estimates with standard errors for all free parameters, if possible.
> - Report standardized and unstandardized indirect effects with standard errors, outline analysis strategy.
> - Report estimates of interactions with standard errors, describe follow-up analyses.

As Peter already noted, centering, not necessarily standardization, is useful for preventing interaction multi-collinearity. Chapter 7 of [this book](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.4324/9780203774441/applied-multiple-regression-correlation-analysis-behavioral-sciences-jacob-cohen-patricia-cohen-stephen-west-leona-aiken) explains this in some detail if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks a million for your answers and sources! I will read the chapter.